# converting strings to different data types in C/C++

Tags: c, xml

How do I smartly convert strings to different variable types in C++ and additionally multiply them by a scale factor?

I'm reading values from xml file; if the attribute in xml called "scale_factor" has occurred, then I need to multiply the value extracted from xml by this factor. My node looks like this:

```
<Pos>
<variableX value="234.2" scale_factor="0.01"/>
<variableY value="233.1" scale_factor="100"/>
<variableZ value="332.2/>
<transparent value = "1"/>
</Pos>
```

and corresponding structure for those values:

```
structure Pos {
float variableX 
float variableY
float variableZ
int transparent;
}
```

retrieving value of scale_factor:

```
int getScaleFactor(xmlNode *node, float *scale_factor)
{
    *scale_factor = 1;
    char *scale_attr  = (char *)xmlGetProp(node, (xmlChar*)"scale_factor");
    if (scale_attr == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("scale factor for: %s is: %f\n", node->name, scale_factor);
        *scale_factor = atof(scale_attr);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

and reading values:

```
    float value;
    float scale_factor;
    int is_scaling;
    xmlNode *cur = node->xmlChildrenNode;
    while (cur != NULL) {
         value = (char *)xmlGetProp(cur, (xmlChar*)"value");
         is_scaling = getScaleFactor(cur, &scale_factor);
         if (!(xmlStrcasecmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"variableX"))) {
              pos.variableX = atof(value);
              if (is_scaling) {
                  pos.variableX = pos.variableX * scale_factor;
              }

         }
         else if (!(xmlStrcasecmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"variableY"))) {
              pos.variableY = atof(value); 
              if (is_scaling) {
                  pos.variableY = pos.variableY * scale_factor;
              }

         }
         else if (!(xmlStrcasecmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"variableZ"))) {
              pos.variableZ = atof(value) 
              if (is_scaling) {
                  pos.variableZ = pos.variableZ * scale_factor;
              }
         else if (!(xmlStrcasecmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"transparent"))) {
              pos.transparent = atoi(value) 
         }
         cur = cur->next;
    }
```

Suppose my node has 134 fields while 76 are float, 33 are ints and rest are strings; I want to avoid creating huge code, but I'm a bit blocked now what I can do conversion in smartest way - so any suggestions are welcome

regards
J

Comment: In the title you say *C/C++*, in the question you say *C++* and in the tags you say *C*, which is it?

Answer (score 0):

In C99/C++, you can do as follows:

```
const char *str[4];
str[0] = "variableX";
str[1] = "variableY";
str[2] = "variableZ";
str[3] = "transparent";
float data[4] = {0.0};

while (cur != NULL) {
     value = (char *)xmlGetProp(cur, (xmlChar*)"value");
     is_scaling = getScaleFactor(cur, &scale_factor);

     for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        if (!(xmlStrcasecmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)str[i]))) {
          data[i] = atof(value);
          if (is_scaling) {
              data[i] = data[i] * scale_factor;
          }
     }

     pos = { .variableX = data[0], .variableY = data[1], 
             .variableZ = data[2], .transparent=(int)(data[3] + 0.5) }; // C99
     // pos = {data[0], data[1], data[2], (int)(data[3]+0.5)};  // C++      
     cur = cur->next;
}
```

Comment: questions: 1) Why c++11 ?  2) is it safe to cast float to int ? 3) what that data[3] + 0.5 means ?

Comment: @JosiP Mistaken here. Earlier C++ also support initialization list. Again for 2&3, `float` should be safely casted to `int`.